# Reduce lags on a nodejs game

Tags: javascript, node.js, server

I have created a nodejs game. i have a setInterval function on the server which sends all the objects near the player. but it doesnt seem to be as smooth as i get when i run it locally. the data package has about 60 objects. here's the server code for sending objects and receiving them on the client. any way to compress the package or reduce the lags? [pinka.herokuapp.com](http://pinka.herokuapp.com)

server:

```
setInterval(function() {
    server.update();

    for(var key in sockets) {
        var socket = sockets[key];
        var player = server.players.filter(function(p) {
            return p.id == socket.id
        })[0];


        var package = [];
        var blobs = server.getNodesInRange(player.centerX, player.centerY);

        for(var i = 0; i < blobs.length; i++) {
            var b = blobs[i];
            package.push({
                x: b.x, 
                y: b.y,
                nick: b.nick,
                size: Math.sqrt(b._mass) * 10,
                hue: b.hue
            });
        };

        socket.emit("update blobs", package);
        socket.emit("leaders", server.getLeaders());

        if(player.blobs.length == 0) {
            socket.emit("dead");
            continue;
        }

        var translateX = player._centerX * player._drawZoom - player.screenWidth / 2;
        var translateY = player._centerY * player._drawZoom - player.screenHeight / 2;


        socket.emit("center and zoom", {
            centerX: translateX,
            centerY: translateY,
            zoom: player._drawZoom
        });
    }
}, 1000/60);
```

client:

```
socket.on("update blobs", function(data) {
   blobs = data;
});
```

this is the whole communication part.

Comment: Check the server ping, if it's low then you need a better server (maybe pay heroku service). You can gzip the package content, but it won't help a lot if it's a small package. Maybe you could restructure the server to work based on user events instead of a fixed timer.

Comment: https://www.site24x7.com/public/t/results-1522502725232.html what does this mean

Comment: `1000/60` you send an update every 20ms ?! Thats faster then the time it takes until the data arrives at the player.

Comment: so does that mean i can never get a smooth gameplay?

Comment: No, because your server-client communication is totally wrong. Try to send as few data as possible and only if an update happens.

Comment: its only 60 objects in a package

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As Jonas W. said, the problem is in the server-client communication.
To be efficient a realtime system with socket.io should be based on events and not in interval checks.

I'd suggest you to have something like this:

- On the **client**, emit a 'user:move' event when the user moves. Prevent too many events to relief the server with unnecessary updates.
- On the **server**, react to a specific 'player:move' event. If the events needs to be broadcasted to the other players, a filter with the ones that can actually "see" the action will avoid unnecessary information for the client too.

An example with pseudo code:

*Client*

```
let updating = false;
let timeout = 0;

// Assuming this function is triggered everytime the user moves (i.e. presses a key)
onUserMove (data) {
    if ('same press as before' && updating) {
        // ignore move if it's the same that has just been done    
        return;
    } else {
        socket.emit('user:move', data);

        // 'Block' the emit for same movement for 20ms
        updating = true;
        clearTimeout(timeout);
        timeout = setTimeout(() => {
            updating = false;
        }, 20);
    }
}
```

*Server*

```
socket.on('user:move', (data) => {
    const dataForTheUser = processingYouAreAlreadyDoing(data);
    socket.emit('data:for:user', dataForTheUser);

    // In case there's information to be sent to every user
    const dataToBroadcast = getDataToBroadcast(data);
    const usersToBroadcast = getCloseUsers(data);

    for (let user in usersToBroadcast) {
        user.socket.emit('whatever:event', dataToBroadcast);
    }
})
```

Comment: Hi @badboy24 I've just added an example trying to explain what I said. Cheers.

Comment: thanks man. but i already modified my code according to ur and some other guys suggestion.